# Архитектура БД для экспорта таблицы

Tags: mysql, база-данных, архитектура

Заранее извиняюсь за много букв.

***1. Входные данные***

Есть 2 таблицы:

```
// theme - тематика
id | num | description

// project - проекты
id | description
```

Эти две таблицы связаны 3-ей таблицей, Много ко Многим.

По структуре: Тема содержит несколько Проектов. По каждому проекту можно узнать сумму затраченных часов, т.е. для Темы рассчитать часы тоже можно.

***2. Решаемая мной задача***

Возникла необходимость создать экспорт шаблонный, настраиваемый (из php) в Excel. Значит шаблон должен храниться, я выбрал место хранение - таблица в БД.  В качестве шаблона подразумевается только шапка таблицы.

***3. Особенности шаблона:***

- Столбцом может быть как **Тема**, так и **Проект**
- **Темы** и **Проекты** могут быть сгруппированы

*К примеру:*

```
Тема1 (Т1)
  - проект1 (п1)
  - проект2 (п2)
Тема2 (Т2)
  - проект1 (п1)
  - проект3 (п3)
Тема3 (Т3)
  - проект1 (п1)
  - проект4 (п4)
```

Данную структуру чтобы можно было сформировать такой шаблон:

```
Группировка1  | Т2 | Т3.п1 | Т3.п4 |
Т1.п1 | Т1.п2 |    |       |       |
```

***4. Мои задумки / начало проектирования***

Создать таблицу, одна строка которой будет содержать либо "Группировку", либо "Тему" (ссылку), либо "Проект" (ссылку) и настройки.

```
id            // 
id_theme      // ссылка на тему
id_project    // ссылка на проект
description   // описание, название колонки
parent        // для темы и проекта - отношение к группировке
order         // порядок
```

сочетание id_theme и id_project формируют вид - Группировка (оба null), Тема (id_project = null), Проект (оба заданы).

Но с такой структурой возникают некоторые сложности с редактированием.

***5. Вопрос***

- В правильную ли меня сторону вообще заносит в подходе к данной задаче?
- Есть ли более лучший (по структуре / производительности / простоте) подход?